# Scraping a web page using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = input('Enter -')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('herf',None))
```

I used this link to test my code `http://www.dr-chuck.com/page1.htm`

The output is: `NONE`

the output should be this link `http://www.dr-chuck.com/page2.htm`

Answer (score 2):

Simple typo, there.

Change 'herf'to 'href'in tags.get

```
  import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url = input('Enter -')
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        print(tag.get('href',None))
```

outputs

```
#http://www.dr-chuck.com/page2.htm
```